# Explanation about using a method of a stored class from another class in php

Tags: php, phpword

So I was reviewing the source code from PHPWord and I have looked all over and can't figure out how this snippet of code works.

```
class PHPWord_Shared_XMLWriter {

/**
 * Internal XMLWriter
 *
 * @var XMLWriter
 */
private $_xmlWriter;

public function __construct($pTemporaryStorage = self::STORAGE_MEMORY, $pTemporaryStorageFolder = './') {
    // Create internal XMLWriter
    $this->_xmlWriter = new XMLWriter();
    ...
}
}
```

So according to my understanding of php the only way to access the $this->_xmlWriter methods is to call it like this:

```
$testClass= new PHPWord_Shared_XMLWriter();
$testClass->_xmlWriter->startDocument();
```

However, in this piece of code from theDocProps.php  this line of code is implemented:

```
$objWriter = new PHPWord_Shared_XMLWriter(PHPWord_Shared_XMLWriter::STORAGE_MEMORY);
$objWriter->startDocument('1.0','UTF-8','yes');
```

How does this work?  I can't replicate it, but it works when I use it in the file.  TO BE CLEAR, there is no method defined by PHPWord_Shared_XMLWriter that is called startDocument().  I feel like I'm missing something really simple but I can't even search right for it.

Thanks!

Comment: `$_xmlWriter` is a private variable, meaning it can't be accessed directly outside that class, so it can't be accessed the way you describe. It seems to me that `startDocument` is just a public method of the `PHPWord_Shared_XMLWriter` class, that's why it can be used that way.

Comment: @edwardmp Actually, it uses the `__call` magic method to make those methods available. Otherwise, your comment would be correct.

Comment: @EdCottrell did not look at the source, was just guessing. Indeed the magic method 'creates' this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at [the entire definition of the class `PHPWord_Shared_XMLWriter`](http://ivanlanin.github.io/PHPWord/api/class-PHPWord_Shared_XMLWriter.html) ([source here](http://ivanlanin.github.io/PHPWord/api/source-class-PHPWord_Shared_XMLWriter.html#32-153)). It uses the [`__call` magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) to pass method calls to `_xmlWriter`:

```
 /**
  * Catch function calls (and pass them to internal XMLWriter)
  *
  * @param unknown_type $function
  * @param unknown_type $args
  */
 public function __call($function, $args)
 {
     try {
         @call_user_func_array(array($this->_xmlWriter, $function), $args);
     } catch (Exception $ex) {
         // Do nothing!
     }
 }
```

By using `call_user_func_array` on `$this->_xmlWriter`, it causes all inaccessible or undefined methods to be passed to the `_xmlWriter` property.

From the docs:

```
__call( unknown_type $function, unknown_type $args )
    Catch function calls (and pass them to internal XMLWriter)
    Parameters
        $function
            unknown_type
            $function
        $args
            unknown_type
            $args
```

Comment: Wow Thank you Ed!  I can't believe I overlooked that function everytime.

Comment: Glad to help! Please remember to accept this as the answer using the check mark on the left. :)